# Extending a resource created inside a module to avoid redundancy to set up a Docker Swarm with Terraform

Tags: docker, terraform

Let's say I've a module which creates some resources that represent a default server. Now I want to inherit this default server to customize it into different directions.

[image]

At the `Manager` node which inherits the `DockerNode` I want to run `docker swarm init` and get the join token. On all `Worker` nodes I want to join with the token.

So in my `main.tf` where I use the `DockerNode` I have defined the nodes like this:

```
module "manager" {
  source = "./modules/swarm-node"

  node_network = {
    network_id = hcloud_network.swarm-network.id
    ip         = "10.0.1.10"
  }
  node_name_prefix       = "swarm-manager"
  server                 = var.server
  docker_compose_version = var.docker_compose_version
  volume_size            = var.volume_size
  volume_filesystem      = var.volume_filesystem
  ssh_keys               = [hcloud_ssh_key.ssh-key-a.name, hcloud_ssh_key.ssh-key-b.name]

  depends_on = [
    hcloud_network_subnet.swarm-network-nodes
  ]
}

module "worker" {
  count  = 2
  source = "./modules/swarm-node"

  node_index = count.index
  node_network = {
    network_id = hcloud_network.swarm-network.id
    ip         = "10.0.1.10${count.index}"
  }
  node_name_prefix       = "swarm-worker"
  server                 = var.server
  docker_compose_version = var.docker_compose_version
  volume_size            = var.volume_size
  volume_filesystem      = var.volume_filesystem
  ssh_keys               = [hcloud_ssh_key.ssh-key-a.name, hcloud_ssh_key.ssh-key-b.name]

  depends_on = [
    hcloud_network_subnet.swarm-network-nodes,
    module.manager
  ]
}
```

1. How to run `docker swarm init` and return the join token on the server resource inside of `module.manager`?
2. How  to join the swarm with each worker?

I've researched this for quite a while:

- Some solutions expose the Docker Daemon over TCP and access it from the worker to get the token. I don't like to expose the Docker Daemon unnecessarily.
- Some solutions copy the base module (in my case `DockerNode`) just to modify one or two lines. I like to to follow DRY.
- Some solutions have an additional shell script, which read the `.tfstate` and SSH into each machine to do further customization. I would like to use Terraform for this with all it's benefits.